# Which known Jedi and Padawan pairs were of the same species?

Tags: star-wars

Canonically, I can only think of three Jedi Masters / Padawan learners that were of the same species:

1. Master Obi-Wan Kenobi and Anakin Skywalker (human)
2. Master Qui-Gon Jinn and Obi-Wan (human)
3. Master Luminara Unduli and Barriss Offee (Mirialan)

**Are there any others?**

Comment: Ulic Qel-Droma and Vilma Sunrider. Kreia and Revan; also Bastia Shan and the amnesiac Revan.

Comment: @SillybutTrue - *"Canonically"*

Comment: @SillybutTrue - Cere Junda and Cal Kestis from Fallen Order. Also not canon

Answer (score 2):

- **Count Dooku and Qui-Gon Jinn (Human)**

  > “Don’t be so sure, my young Jedi,” Count Dooku immediately replied, an offsetting smile on his face, one of confidence and calm. **“You forget that Qui-Gon was once my apprentice just as you were once his.”**
  >
  > <sub><sup>Attack of the Clones - Official Novelisation</sup></sub>
- **Count Dooku and Rael Averross (Human)**

  > **RAEL AVERROSS:** *Male. Dooku’s first Padawan, seen as a Jedi Knight. Thick Ringo Vindan accent.*

> <sub><sup>Star Wars: Dooku</sup></sub>

Depending on your definition of 'Padawan' (e.g. that they're an apprentice to a bona fide Jedi), we can also include;

- **Luke Skywalker and Ben Solo (Human)**
- **Luke Skywalker and Rey (Human)**
- **Kanan Jarrus and Ezra Bridger (Human)**